# Rcpp random shuffle: reproducing results across operating systems

Tags: r, rcpp

I am writing a R package that utilizes the Rcpp package. Until now, I have been working and testing on macOS Catalina with R version 4.0.0. Using `set.seed` from R, I can get reproducible results from my Mac. However, when testing on a windows 10 machine (also with R 4.0.0) I get a different result (using the same seed).

In the package, I call `std::random_shuffle` to generate a permutation. I am using the code from [the Rcpp website](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/stl-random-shuffle/index.html) to do this. In C++, it is:

```c++
#include<Rcpp.h>

inline int randWrapper(const int n) { return floor(unif_rand()*n); }

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector randomShuffle(Rcpp::NumericVector a) {

    // clone a into b to leave a alone
    Rcpp::NumericVector b = Rcpp::clone(a);

    std::random_shuffle(b.begin(), b.end(), randWrapper);

    return b;
}
```

Then it can be sourced from R and called as

```r
a <- 1:8
set.seed(42)
randomShuffle(a)
```

Running this code I get `8 1 4 2 7 5 3 6` on my Mac and `1 4 3 7 5 8 6 2` on Windows.

At first I thought this might be due to differences in the way `unif_rand()` is implemented on the two operating systems, but when I tested

```c++
#include<Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector rint() {
    Rcpp::NumericVector a(1);
    a[0] = unif_rand();
    return a;
}
```

I get the same result of `0.914806` on both machines. The same thing happens if I replace `unif_rand()` with `R::runif(0,1)`. I believe that the results for the Mac are the same for both `g++` and `clang++`.

Any advice or insight on how to fix this (if possible) would be appreciated!

Comment: would the RcppSugar sample function help you?  https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/issues/794

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *think* you are getting confused because `std::random_shuffle()` is in fact a standard C++ library function and *its RNG is not related to R*.  So that you are getting different results on macOS and Windows is, I am guessing, due the different C++ libraries.

This line of thinking is then confirmed by your results of getting the `runif()` or `unif_rand()` values.  It's just that those values are not used by `std::random_shuffle()`.

So as @BenBolker hinted, for *reproducible* results across OSs you may want to stick to R (and Rcpp) functions.